# How to pass dynamic json request body in postman

Tags: dynamic, postman

I have a POST request where i need to pass some parameters dynamically since my code is checking for a duplicate entry. I tried writing a pre request script and then setting the global variables and tried to access it in my request. It is not working. PFB, the details

Pre-request Script

postman.setGlobalVariable("firstname", (text + parseInt(Math.random()*10000)).toString());
postman.setGlobalVariable("lastname", text + parseInt(Math.random()*10000));

Body

{
  "request": 
    {
        "firstName":"{{firstname}}",
        "middleName":"mani",
        "lastName":"{{lastname}}"
}
}

Here firstName is getting passed as {{firstname}} instead of random string.

Comment: if it is for test purpose why dont you send it hard coded rather than dynamic.{{firstname}} is a placeholder in angular  i believe and you get first name there because of angular implementation . i think

Comment: Yes, it is for test purpose, but my business logic will not accept duplicate data (combination of firstname , lastname and few other details ) so i need to pass random dynamic data

Comment: I believe the server checks for duplicates .Try posting the same combination again and check if validation occurs

Comment: Yes, server checks for duplication. I want to use postman runner for loading data for test purpose, for that purpose i need to pass dynamic names , so that i can load multiple data.

Answer (score 13):

You ca do it by adding

```
var rnd = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("firstname", "fname"+rnd);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("lastname", "lname"+rnd);
```

in the Pre-request Script section.

And then adding

```
{ 
"firstName":"{{firstname}}", 
"middleName":"mani", 
"lastName":"{{lastname}}" 
}
```

in the body.

I tried it in both Postman and Newman and is working perfectly generating a random first name and last name.

Answer (score 5):

```
{ 
 "request": { 
   "firstName":"{{$randomInt}}",
   "middleName":"mani",
   "lastName":"{{$randomInt}}" 
  }
}
```

No need to add global variables.
Postman have dynamic variable `{{$randomInt}}` which Adds a random integer between 0 and 1000